# How can I stop unit tests from using testresult folders

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I and a collegue of mine are running unit tests for the same project (we are getting the project files via TFS so the files themselves are the same for both of us). Also our installation of visual studio is essentially the same version (with him having set something different than me as standard for theme and keyboard. But that aside we even have the same addons installed).

When I run the unit tests they are run in the debug folder of the unit test project. If he runs them they are run in the testresults folder. We already checked the build configurations and they are the same for both of us (with deploy unchecked for both).

So my question here is how can we get his visual studio to stop running unit tests in the testresults folder and instead run them in his debug folder?
*(And on that also it would be interesting why essentially identical installations of visual studio show such a different behaviour)*

*As an addon to this: For specific reasons the unit tests NEED to be run in the debug folder as it causes troubles if not*

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578587/how-to-make-unit-test-run-in-bin-folder

Comment: ru using resharper ?

Comment: @wal no we are not using reshaper. We are using dotcover but that is it.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski No I didn't. Hmmm question is quite similar there with the exception being the VS versions (I don't think that that makes a real difference) and that on one PC we run into the problem and on one PC not (hmm interestingly he hadn't accepted any of the answers)

Comment: @Thomas I am using R#/Dotcover - assemblies were being copied to `TestResults` folder for me even tho Shadow Copy was disabled. I just toggled the settings (off/on including enabling/disabling) so it looks like this (after toggling) http://imgur.com/Yq1bkJG - hrmm on second thght you may not even see these settings given you arent using R#

Comment: @wal sorry to ask there but is that the same as jetbrains dotcover or something else? (I'm not that used to the different product names,... still when it comes to visual studio)

Comment: yes it is jetbrains dotcover - i'm just not sure if dotCover (installed without r#) provides the unit test runner that ships with Resharper (it may but I dont install it standalone). Under Resharper menu item you can look for Options. UPDATE: it looks like it does provide it, so you need to find a dialog that looks like this http://imgur.com/72j2aGi

Comment: @wal I looked onto m colleagues pc and it looks like neither he nor I do have that one dialog (or more precisely a dialog with these options in it)