# Unable to run unit tests in the Bin Folder c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

Background: I have a consuming a 3rd party class library which uses `typeof(myClassFactory).Assembly.Location`
to determine its location and then uses this to load another dll. This is breaking because the second dll is not copied to the temporary location. Therefore I want to make the unit tests run from within the /bin folder.
I'm using Vs2017 pro with xUnit and tried the VS test runner and resharper and both behave the same.

**What I've tried so far**: I've tried creating a test.runsettings file and setting the following:

`<DeploymentEnabled>false</DeploymentEnabled>`

as suggest here [How to make unit test run in bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578587/how-to-make-unit-test-run-in-bin-folder)

however the code is still  executing in  `c:/users/myuserName/Local/Temp/{someGuid}/{someguid}/....etc`

**Question**: How do i make it run in the /bin directory?

Comment: Consider a redesign. abstract that out as it is an implementation concern. That way you can mock it when testing to what ever path you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking. The code exists inside the DLL under test, and is used to load further resources. It is also legacy code which is very unlikely to be redesigned to allow unit testing.

Comment: Add a direct reference to the missing dll to the test project? That may force VS to copy it to where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue, it was to do with xUnit not using the .runsettings file.

To fix this, I added a new file called `xunit.runner.json` and added the following code:

`{
  "shadowCopy": false
}`

I added this to the root of the solution and then set it to be copied to the output by right clicking on the file:

Properties > Copy to Output Directory

set to 'Copy if newer'

This made it work