# run Unittests from bin Folder instead of ..\Out\... in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I am working with 'VS 2017, Version 15.9.12', I work with a Unit-Testproject but currently when I debug a test my IDE always runs the Test in the "....\TestResults\testuser_notebook1065 2019-06-11 09_23_41\Out\chromedriver.exe" Folder. Already read this thread: [How to make unit test run in bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578587/how-to-make-unit-test-run-in-bin-folder?rq=1)

And created a .testsettings-File which looks like that:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Buildserver" id="a31724c1-140a-435b-a39d-dff082acb2af" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
 <DeploymentItem filename="..\..\..\Facelift\Binaries\SystemTestsFacelift\" />
  </Deployment>
  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
            <Directory Path="D:\Builds\Facelift\Binaries\SystemTestsFacelift" includeSubDirectories="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Changed in in the IDE the following settings:

- "Test", "Test Settings", ".... Path to my .testsetting File"
- "Test", "Test Settings", "Keep Test Execution Engine Running"

Want to change the running Folder to "...\Tests\SystemTestsFacelift\bin\Debug"-

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: I have no experience running a browser test. But do you describe the path of the test **results** rather than the **executable dll**?

Comment: When running MSTest it seems that it creates a temporary output folder like "D:\SVN\Source\Lidat\TestResults\..myC-Time\....." I have to say that I have no idea how to change this and tell MSTest to execute the .dll --> The file D:\SVN-Lidat\Source\Lidat\TestResults\lbhkaa4_LBHNB1065 2019-06-11 15_43_02\Out\chromedriver.exe does not exist.

Comment: Why are you sure the tests are running from the `Out` folder? Are there any `.dll` files at all? Please help us to help you, be sure your question is correct, before trying to get an answer.

Comment: What effect of the location of the run for you?

Comment: Exactly that is was I don't know. 
1. Why does MSTest or Visual Studio execute unittests in the Out?
2. How do I fix Nr 1. can I change somehow that path? --> I need the debug folder for the test execution because there my chromedriver.exe will be copied ..